# how to connect mongo with elasticsearch using logstash?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

I want to connect mongodb with elasticsearch. I have used logstash-input-mongodb plugin, but this doesn't take my elasticsearch data updates. So when i update a document at mongodb it doesn't change at elasticsearch. I have searched through web but couldn't find a  way to fix it? Is it a bug? 
Which other plugins or tools do you suggest me to use for making the connection?

Comment: Try using mongo-connector

Comment: i used mongo-connector it does not store large data from mongodb to elastic

Answer (score 0):

You could try [mongoosastic](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic) however I think its community is a little bit small and there have been practically no updates since a year ago.