# How to sync data from mongodb to elasticsearch using Logstash

Tags: mongodb, kibana

i have data in mongodb database and now i want to visualize realtime data in kibana .if data changes in mongodb it should be reflect in kibana.so how to implement it ...please guide me to implement this

Comment: You should check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374216/what-is-the-alternate-for-elastic-river-mongodb-plugin-supported-by-elasticsear/35375990#35375990

Comment: i used mongo-connector it does not store all data from mongodb to elastic and i am not sure will logstash can do...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447439/how-to-connect-mongo-with-elasticsearch-using-logstash

Comment: The problem of `mongo-connector` to doesn't store all data is correct as mentioned in its self document, So, There is a solution in same document, that is `DocManager` class. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-mongo-connector?source=post_page---------------------------

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**Monstache**](https://rwynn.github.io/monstache-site/). It is a sync daemon written in Go that continuously indexes your MongoDB collections into Elasticsearch.